# How do I install a GFCI in a box with two 2-wire cables and one 3-wire cable?

Tags: gfci

[image]I need some help please.  I'm replacing a standard receptacle with GFCI but the instructions that came with the GFCI doesn't explain how to make the connections when when there is a 3-wire cable.  Even more confusing is this box has 3 cables feeding into it (one 3-wire and two 2-wire).  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Is the tab or fin between the screws on the hot side of the receptacle still present, or has it been broken off?  Also, is this the only receptacle you want to GFCI protect, or are there more receptacles involved?

Comment: The tab is still present.

Comment: Is this receptacle the only one you wish to GFCI protect, or are there other receptacles you want to provide GFCI protection to as well?

Comment: There is another receptacle in the kitchen but it is at the very end so it only had one 2-wire cable feeding into it and I was able to replace that with GFCI.  In case it's helpful, the switch you see in the photos controls my garbage disposal.

Comment: Backstabs used major bad , any answer on the tab broken ? Between the “sockets” ? It makes a difference because GFCI receptacles can’t be split.

Comment: @EdBeal I’m looking right at it.  It’s not split.

Comment: @EdBeal https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198162/how-do-i-install-a-gfci-in-a-box-with-two-2-wire-cables-and-one-3-wire-cable#comment356109_198162

Comment: @Freeman  what is your link showing link only answers and comments are frowned upon.

Comment: @EdBeal it's a link to the comment where the OP answered the question before you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy.  Most GFCI receptacles have a method to attach 2 wires to each LINE screw.

That is exactly what you do.  The two black wires go on the brass LINE screw.  The 1 white wire goes on the silver LINE screw.  And you're done.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it appeared to work.  So I put away my tools and I plugged a cell phone charger into a different GFCI outlet that is located at the end of the line. Shortly after 10 minutes or so, this new GFCI outlet that you showed me how to replace blew.  There was a spark, a puff of smoke and the breaker tripped.  There was nothing plugged into this new GFCI. What went wrong?

Comment: The switch in the picture controls the garbage disposal and is on a 20 amp circuit.  The circuit that I'm putting this GFCI onto is a 20 amp circuit as well.  I made sure to buy a 20 amp rated GFCI.

Comment: I’m sorry that happened, but it doesn’t make any sense for that to happen.   The two black wires were tied together previously, as your photo of the “tab” plainly shows.  It would really help to see a picture of the GFCI and how the wires were attached; maybe something went wrong there.

Comment: I disconnected the GFCI, but I marked in this photo how I connected the wires to the GFCI.  You could see the discoloration where it blew on the white neutral side.  The GFCI is ELECTECK 20A GFCI Outlet.  I don't know if I am allowed to link to the product page but here it is if it's allowed. 
 https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07ZRFWJSM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/kRp2foZpNLHopzA77

Comment: @EthanN Wow. I initially feared it blew on the hot side due to through-current. But it blew on the NEUTRAL with nothing plugged in and nothing on LOAD.  That’s insane!  This was clearly and overcurrent burn-up, but the only possible load on that neutral was *the GFCI itself*.  **It can only be a faulty GFCI**.  Noting the product listing, it’s a Chinese cheapie off eBay (Amazon Marketplace, same thing), claims ETL but the device isn’t marked ETL, no screw torque listing either.  It looks to be counterfeit.

Comment: Good to know.  I shared with Amazon the product quality and safety concern.  Thanks for all your help!  It looks like I should be able to connect a GFCI like you suggested as soon as I buy new quality GFCI outlets.